# CNN model predict the same value in most part of cases

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a CNN model for image classification.

There are nine classes and every class have 1000 images.

Here's my code

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu',kernel_initializer='random_uniform', input_shape=(128,646,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=(64,321,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have tried this on MNIST dataset and it's works will

but on my dataset it always predict the same value.

(True Label above and predict label value bottom)

```
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[0.11161657 0.11246169 0.11564494 0.11465651 0.11153363 0.10664304
  0.11097018 0.11052497 0.10594855]
 [0.11161657 0.11246169 0.11564494 0.11465651 0.11153363 0.10664304
  0.11097018 0.11052497 0.10594855]
 [0.11161657 0.11246169 0.11564494 0.11465651 0.11153363 0.10664304
  0.11097018 0.11052497 0.10594855]
 [0.11161657 0.11246169 0.11564494 0.11465651 0.11153363 0.10664304
  0.11097018 0.11052497 0.10594855]
 [0.11161657 0.11246169 0.11564494 0.11465651 0.11153363 0.10664304
  0.11097018 0.11052497 0.10594855]]
```

[Accuracy curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYwqf.png)
[Loss curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OipIa.png)

I have tried to change the **initializer, optimizer, loss function, more epoch,** ... still nothing change.

But when I 
1.set the both Conv2D kernel number to 1 
2.set the 1st Conv2D activate function to tanh

the model start predict different value for the input but performance not will.

I'm mainly confuse about
1.Setting the kernel number to 1 seems uncommon,but in my experience it avoid predicting the same value.
2.The value of the input image are all greater than zero,but setting the activate function to tanh can also change the result to different predicted classes?

Besides, the image size is 128*646 
Every image value is in the range of 0~80

```
array([[[33.74863434],
        [27.84932709],
        [22.6257019 ],
        ...,
        [21.47132492],
        [19.61938477],
        [14.22393227]],

       [[16.31633759],
        [29.69265747],
        [25.40621376],
        ...,
        [28.50727081],
        [11.46302605],
        [ 4.04836655]],

       [[ 9.1305275 ],
        [10.00378227],
        [28.46733665],
        ...,
        [23.54629517],
        [20.91897202],
        [ 1.38314819]],

       ...,

       [[63.33175659],
        [66.34197998],
        [68.40023804],
        ...,
        [73.8707428 ],
        [68.64536285],
        [67.72910309]],

       [[67.61167908],
        [67.59188843],
        [66.96526337],
        ...,
        [70.63095856],
        [74.70448303],
        [72.90202332]],

       [[71.49047852],
        [74.54782104],
        [69.39613342],
        ...,
        [80.        ],
        [80.        ],
        [80.        ]]])
```

**Update**

My dataset is from Free Music Archive

Including track audio data (.mp3) and track metadata(genre,artist,...)

I chose the small version (8000 tracks) and converted into spectrogram by libROSA package.

Just like this link [Using CNNs and RNNs for Music Genre Recognition](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-cnns-and-rnns-for-music-genre-recognition-2435fb2ed6af)

But I'd like to try CNN model only first.

The spectrogram converted by libROSA package have the size of 128*646.

The row data is like this

```
array([[-65.06227 , -47.759537, -44.17627 , ..., -39.40817 , -41.736862,
        -25.19515 ],
       [-65.40295 , -52.76098 , -49.17935 , ..., -16.40555 , -16.314035,
        -17.56438 ],
       [-69.481834, -56.676388, -50.506615, ..., -16.358843, -16.072405,
        -18.807785],
       ...,
       [-79.42308 , -59.743004, -36.382896, ..., -46.371193, -42.364635,
        -50.037727],
       [-80.      , -63.419754, -41.73323 , ..., -50.383797, -46.90663 ,
        -55.136078],
       [-80.      , -73.820724, -52.94601 , ..., -63.188026, -56.469948,
        -60.473305]], dtype=float32)
```

I divided the value by 80 and calculated the absolute value for those spectrogram as CNN model input

Comment: The problem isn't that your model is predicting the same class all the time, as much as it hasn't learned to distinguish between classes at all. Take a look at the predictions `[0.11161657 0.11246169 0.11564494 0.11465651 0.11153363 0.10664304
  0.11097018 0.11052497 0.10594855]`. It is giving the same probability for all classes! Your code seems OK. Sometimes this is something very simple, e.g. you haven't normalized the images and are using a very small learning rate (i.e. the default for optimizers).

Comment: nothing seems to be wrong here. can you include your preprocessing steps?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my input image value is all in the range of zero to eighty, do I still need to normalize those data?

Comment: Already added the preprocessing part , hope that helps.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share the complete code or google colab file to reproduce your issue so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Yes.It's seems I was setting the kernel amount too small to cause the model can't learn enough.When the amount greater than maybe 50 ,it start predict more acurrate.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the Solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments Section, for the **benefit of the Community**. Adding more suggestions as well.

Increasing the Number of `Kernels` or `Filters` to more than 50, like 64 has resulted in improved Accuracy. This is because more number of `Kernels/Filters` improves the Representational Power of the `Model`, especially, when the Data is not very simple to learn.

In order to improve the `Accuracy`, the Model can be changed from

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu',kernel_initializer='random_uniform', input_shape=(128,646,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=(64,321,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9, activation = 'softmax'))
```

to

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5,5), 
activation='relu',kernel_initializer='random_uniform', 
input_shape=(128,646,1))) # Increased the Number of Kernels in this Conv2D 
Layer
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', 
input_shape=(64,321,1))) # Increased the Number of Kernels in this Conv2D 
Layer
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu',
kernel_initializer='normal')) #Increased the Number of Neurons in this Dense 
Layer
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Also, the `Input Data` is in the Range `0 to 80`. Normalizing it to values between `0 and 1` will result in more better `accuracy`.

General Pre-Processing steps are shown below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

Test_Dir = 'Dogs_Vs_Cats_Small/test/cats'
Image_File = os.path.join(Test_Dir, 'cat.1545.jpg')

Image = image.load_img(Image_File, target_size = (128,646))

Image_Tensor = image.img_to_array(Image)

Image_Tensor = tf.expand_dims(Image_Tensor, axis = 0)

Image_Tensor = Image_Tensor/255.0
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

It's because the number of input and output neuron given in the code.
Change with actual input neurons and output neuron (total class to be predicted)
I had the same error and corrected this way.
Thank you.